# Iterate over list of objects and create nodes by properties of objects Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a list of objects, the objects have different properties.

```
array = [{name: 'Armen', age: 26}, {name: 'Alex', profession: 'Scientist'}]
```

I need to iterate over list and create nodes with properties provided by objects. Which is the easiest and best practice way to do it? Thanks in advance! I have tried to use unwind both for list and object keys

```
WITH array AS nodes 
UNWIND nodes AS node
UNWIND keys(node) AS prop 
WITH node, prop
MERGE (man: Man {prop:node[prop]}) 
RETURN man
```

but in this case I get one node for each property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unwinding `prop` will result in separate rows for each property and that is why it doesn't work. You can keep the properties in one collection like this,

```
WITH [{name: 'Armen', age: 26}, {name: 'Alex', profession: 'Scientist'}] AS nodes 
UNWIND nodes AS node
WITH node, properties(node) as props
MERGE (man:Man {name: props.name}) ON CREATE SET man += props
RETURN man
```

(i'm assuming that `name` is common to all items)

Comment: Thanks for answer. Could you please explain why do I need to use WITH operator and properties function?

Comment: As I can see from your own answer, it is indeed simpler to just use the 'node'. No need for the 'WITH". I used it to the props into a separate variable

Comment: Thanks for this, But in case I want to remove some conditional properties (key, values) from props like start from "create" keyword then how we can do?
Can you please help me

Comment: @AkshayPingle Not sure what you mean. You can check out list comprehensions https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-list-comprehension which may give you a way to filter out some properties

Answer (score 1):

As [@aldrin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74057/aldrin) and Cobra from [Neo4j Community](https://community.neo4j.com/t/iterate-over-list-of-objects-and-create-nodes-by-properties-of-objects/46205) showed, I can add properties with `SET`. Here is the easiest way I found to do it.

```
WITH [{name: 'Armen', age: 26}, {name: 'Alex', profession: 'Scientist'}] 
AS nodes 
UNWIND nodes AS node
CREATE (man:Man)
SET man += node 
RETURN man
```

I added Ids to my nodes so I can create and update nodes by just one query.

```
WITH [{id: 0, name: 'Armen', age: 26}, {id: 1, name: 'Alex', profession: 'Scientist'}] AS nodes 
UNWIND nodes AS node
MERGE (man:Man {id: node.id})
SET man += node 
RETURN man
```